# Flask Socketio on Heroku Client Side Connect Function Runs but not Server Side

Tags: python, heroku, flask, flask-socketio

I have this code on the client side:

```
player_id = Math.round(Math.random() * 5000);
your_sock = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/');  //io.connect('');  //io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
your_sock.on('connect', function(){
    your_sock.emit('player_connect', {'id': player_id});
    console.log('I have connected with ID ' + player_id);
});
```

and this code on the server side:

```
@socker.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('THE HANDLE CONNECT FUNCTION WAS WRITTEN')
    try:
        socker.emit('testing', {'hello': 'hi'})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I see the "I have connected with ID 27" on the Chrome developer log, meaning the client side socket connection function was run, however, the server side does not log "THE HANDLE CONNECT FUNCTION WAS RUN". **Note, any other logs I add outside of socket functions are logged so it's not a problem with printing to heroku logs**

Requirements.txt

```
click==6.7
dnspython==1.15.0
eventlet==0.24.1
Flask==1.0.2
flask-heroku==0.1.9
Flask-SocketIO==3.0.1
greenlet==0.4.14
gunicorn==19.9.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
monotonic==1.5
python-engineio==2.2.0
python-socketio==2.0.0
six==1.11.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 --no-sendfile --log-level=DEBUG --log-file=- --preload --chdir nickdima wsgi:app
```

The wsgi.py file referenced in my procfile:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/app/nickdima")


from __init__ import create_app

app = create_app()
```

Heroku Logs:

```
2018-09-05T22:11:03.936310+00:00 app[web.1]: hello logs
2018-09-05T22:11:03.938061+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.31.74.203 - - [05/Sep/2018:22:11:03 +0000] "GET /test_pong/test_pong_game HTTP/1.1" 200 1022 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36"
2018-09-05T22:11:03.938237+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:11:03 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2018-09-05T22:11:03.982684+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:11:03 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2018-09-05T22:11:04.308695+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:11:04 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] GET /socket.io/
2018-09-05T22:11:04.313499+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.31.74.203 - - [05/Sep/2018:22:11:04 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1536185465659-0 HTTP/1.1" 200 119 "http://www.nickdima.com/test_pong/test_pong_game" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36"
2018-09-05T22:11:04.313924+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:11:04 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2018-09-05T22:11:04.352762+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:11:04 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] POST /socket.io/
2018-09-05T22:11:04.359377+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.31.74.203 - - [05/Sep/2018:22:11:04 +0000] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1536185465714-1&sid=bcd9d3c54362405a91a6ec22c4633c1c HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "http://www.nickdima.com/test_pong/test_pong_game" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36"
2018-09-05T22:11:04.360509+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:11:04 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2018-09-05T22:11:04.365782+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:11:04 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] GET /socket.io/
2018-09-05T22:11:04.400864+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:11:04 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] GET /socket.io/
2018-09-05T22:11:04.422792+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.255.135 - - [05/Sep/2018:22:11:04 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1536185465722-2&sid=bcd9d3c54362405a91a6ec22c4633c1c HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "http://www.nickdima.com/test_pong/test_pong_game" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36"
2018-09-05T22:11:04.423589+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:11:04 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2018-09-05T22:11:04.312971+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path= "/socket.io/?EIO= 3&transport= polling&t=1536185465659-0" host=www.nickdima.com request_id=89f6de3d-cfa2-41eb-879e-7aaba5052a60 fwd="71.206.187.35" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=419 protocol=http
2018-09-05T22:11:04.357827+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path= "/socket.io/?EIO= 3&transport= polling&t= 1536185465714-1&sid=bcd9d3c54362405a91a6ec22c4633c1c" host=www.nickdima.com request_id=d9505e27-b0c9-49b0-9a2e-0ff31a832e7f fwd="71.206.187.35" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=260 protocol=http
2018-09-05T22:11:04.422606+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path= "/socket.io/?EIO= 3&transport= polling&t= 1536185465722-2&sid=bcd9d3c54362405a91a6ec22c4633c1c" host=www.nickdima.com request_id=d0c37303-d208-4a27-967b-07c03162be1d fwd="71.206.187.35" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=65ms status=200 bytes=254 protocol=http
2018-09-05T22:11:03.937943+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/test_pong/test_pong_game" host=www.nickdima.com request_id=e489d0f1-4a9a-4854-8e11-a43134dae135 fwd="71.206.187.35" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=1184 protocol=http
2018-09-05T22:12:25.105722+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:12:25 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2018-09-05T22:14:41.196614+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:14:41 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
```

**Notice the "Hello Logs", that is a separate python statement that prints when the page loads to ensure that I can print to heroku logs**

pre-load logs:

```
 chdir: /app/nickdima
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417586+00:00 app[web.1]: daemon: False
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417589+00:00 app[web.1]: pidfile: None
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417592+00:00 app[web.1]: user: 5991
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417593+00:00 app[web.1]: group: 5991
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417588+00:00 app[web.1]: raw_env: []
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417595+00:00 app[web.1]: umask: 0
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417591+00:00 app[web.1]: worker_tmp_dir: None
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417596+00:00 app[web.1]: initgroups: False
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417598+00:00 app[web.1]: tmp_upload_dir: None
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417606+00:00 app[web.1]: secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417608+00:00 app[web.1]: forwarded_allow_ips: ['*']
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417609+00:00 app[web.1]: accesslog: -
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417611+00:00 app[web.1]: disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417616+00:00 app[web.1]: access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417618+00:00 app[web.1]: errorlog: -
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417619+00:00 app[web.1]: loglevel: DEBUG
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417620+00:00 app[web.1]: capture_output: False
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417622+00:00 app[web.1]: logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417623+00:00 app[web.1]: logconfig: None
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417625+00:00 app[web.1]: logconfig_dict: {}
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417626+00:00 app[web.1]: syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417627+00:00 app[web.1]: syslog: False
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417629+00:00 app[web.1]: syslog_prefix: None
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417630+00:00 app[web.1]: syslog_facility: user
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417632+00:00 app[web.1]: enable_stdio_inheritance: False
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417634+00:00 app[web.1]: statsd_prefix:
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417636+00:00 app[web.1]: proc_name: None
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417633+00:00 app[web.1]: statsd_host: None
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417639+00:00 app[web.1]: pythonpath: None
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417646+00:00 app[web.1]: on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7f9b84c2d1e0>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417637+00:00 app[web.1]: default_proc_name: wsgi:app
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417651+00:00 app[web.1]: pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7f9b84c2d510>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417640+00:00 app[web.1]: paste: None
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417652+00:00 app[web.1]: post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7f9b84c2d620>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417648+00:00 app[web.1]: on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7f9b84c2d2f0>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417656+00:00 app[web.1]: worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7f9b84c2d840>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417649+00:00 app[web.1]: when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7f9b84c2d400>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417657+00:00 app[web.1]: worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7f9b84c2d950>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417658+00:00 app[web.1]: pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7f9b84c2da60>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417654+00:00 app[web.1]: post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7f9b84c2d730>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417660+00:00 app[web.1]: pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7f9b84c2db70>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417666+00:00 app[web.1]: nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7f9b84c2df28>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417664+00:00 app[web.1]: worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7f9b84c2de18>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417669+00:00 app[web.1]: proxy_protocol: False
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417670+00:00 app[web.1]: proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417661+00:00 app[web.1]: post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7f9b84c2dbf8>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417663+00:00 app[web.1]: child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7f9b84c2dd08>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417673+00:00 app[web.1]: certfile: None
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417667+00:00 app[web.1]: on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7f9b84cc00d0>
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417675+00:00 app[web.1]: ssl_version: 2
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417677+00:00 app[web.1]: ca_certs: None
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417680+00:00 app[web.1]: do_handshake_on_connect: False
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417672+00:00 app[web.1]: keyfile: None
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417760+00:00 app[web.1]: raw_paste_global_conf: []
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417676+00:00 app[web.1]: cert_reqs: 0
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417679+00:00 app[web.1]: suppress_ragged_eofs: True
2018-09-05T22:38:29.417682+00:00 app[web.1]: ciphers: TLSv1
2018-09-05T22:38:30.303852+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:38:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2018-09-05T22:38:30.304961+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:38:30 +0000] [4] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
2018-09-05T22:38:30.305184+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:38:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:46524 (4)
2018-09-05T22:38:30.305414+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:38:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: eventlet
2018-09-05T22:38:30.313804+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:38:30 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2018-09-05T22:38:30.361254+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:38:30 +0000] [4] [DEBUG] 1 workers
2018-09-05T22:38:30.851461+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-09-05T22:38:30.832213+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:38:30 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2018-09-05T22:38:30.833331+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-05 22:38:30 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
```

Comment: Are you sure the module that has your connect handler in the server is being imported? These handlers work in the same way as Flask routes, they need to be imported so that they are registered with the framework.

Comment: @Miguel Ah-ha... I moved all my code into the __init__.py file and it works. But not when events are in other files. There's something odd happening with my imports. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed an import error where the event handlers were not being imported in the __init__.py file that contained my app factory, thus they were not registered to my app.

To fix this I added a socket_instance.py file to my root directory that contains

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
```

and imported that in my __init__.py file as well as in all my event handler creation files.

Then from any files I can now import my socketio object as such:

```
from socket_instance import socketio
```